# What is the single word for "make something slow"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

There is the verb *[quicken](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quicken)* to make something quick or faster, but Merriam-Webster doesn't list *[slowen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestions/slowen)*.  What is the verb to **make something slow** (as in 'reduce in speed', not 'something that is slow')?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The word **slow** itself can be used as a verb. It is an antonym for **[quicken](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quicken)**

**Slow**, from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slow)

> *verb*
>   to make (something, such as a car) move at a lower speed; to begin to move at a lower speed;  to become slower

*"the car slowed to a halt"*

Comment: *"The driver slowed his car to a halt"* as an example of the transitive use

Answer (score 21):

You can also technically use "retard", but people will probably more often associate this with mental disability.

**Retard**, from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retard)

> *verb*
>   to slow down the development or progress of (something)

Comment: "Retard" as a verb, clearly applied to an inanimate object, might still work.

Comment: I disagree that people would associate 'retard' with mental disability.  That is a very specific sense of the word.

Comment: "Retarded" became a euphamism for mental disability based on its original meaning of "slowed" (in the sense of slowed development), but in many parts of the world the word has since become more commonly used as a pejorative and potentially offensive term for people with mental disabilities. In technical contexts it's fine (e.g. "fire retardant" meaning a substance that slows fire), but outside of such contexts, be aware that you might be misunderstood.

Comment: @Chenmunka My immediate reaction with full context was *No*, so trust me, especially in the UK, it's not an acceptable synonym.

Comment: I am from the UK and retard is a perfectly acceptable, widely used, synonym for slow down.  It is true that its sense of mentally retarded is often used perjoratively but no more so than many other terms

Comment: I am from the UK and retard is an entirely unacceptable term, used exclusively as an offensive word for people with mental disabilities. I suspect Chenmunka is used to interacting only with a small subset of the population (academics maybe?), for I can assure you that among the "common" people, retard is very definitely an insult first and foremost.

Comment: @user568458 In line with your idea, I think it entirely depends on context. E.g. "We erected a barrier to retard the spread of the contagion." I don't think it necessarily has to be a technical context, but the use of retard as a non-pejorative definitely has a more formal feel to it in my opinion. I doubt anyone is going to interpret retard as an insult in the example I gave.

Comment: @cartographer Yes, that's a good example. But I'd be very careful when using it in the context of people. For example, if in a work meeting someone said "Unfortunately, including Bob's team has retarded this project", unless it was a meeting of academics, scientists etc, I wouldn't be surprised if someone unfamiliar with the original meaning misinterpreted it as a very crude and offensive insult to Bob.

Comment: [Retarded bombs](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/retarded+bomb) are the first things that come to mind regarding examples of the word being used in its original context.

Comment: I don't understand why this one-line answer with major limitations in its usability has got as many votes as the accepted answer and more votes than any of the alternatives which are more widely usable...

Comment: @Benubird Absolutely - this really shouldn't be the top answer because it has huge potential for misunderstanding and I'd recommend against anyone using the word without thoroughly understanding the social implications around it.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned the difference in pronunciation.  When used as a verb (and similar), I'm accustomed to having the emphasis on the second syllable, whereas the noun/epithet has emphasis on the first syllable.  I think that lessens the likelihood of confusion.  (That still leaves the matter of taste, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Good point, the "ee" sound on the first syllable is when you get in trouble, whereas r'tahrd is much safer.

Answer (score 18):

If you mean to actively intervene and make something else slower, you can use **impede**. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impede):

> ### Impede
>
> To slow the movement, progress, or action of (someone or something)
>
> *Transitive verb* - To interfere with or slow the progress of
>
> - *He claims that economic growth is being impeded by government regulations.*
> - *The soldiers could not impede the enemy's advance.*

For example, you could say "We thought that hiring more staff would quicken progess on this project, but actually, the extra hassle has impeded us".

This is a good choice if you want to emphasise that one thing is making another, different, separate thing slower (as opposed to something slowing naturally).

It's often used for abstract things. For example, ["to impede progress"](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/to%20impede%20progress) is a pretty common phrase.

Comment: "hinder" and "hindered" are probably the more commonly used synonyms of impede.Or, at least in the UK.

Comment: I considered adding "hinder" but I think it's a little closer to "interfere with" than "slow down" - hindering something could mean harming its quality as well as its speed. But they are very similar.

Answer (score 13):

Consider, ***hamper***

> To slow the movement, progress, or action of (someone or something.)
>
> *Construction is hampering traffic on the highway.*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hamper)

Comment: Best choice for non-physical movement.

Answer (score 11):

There is also **decelerate**, which is the opposite of accelerate.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decelerate)

> *verb*
>    to move slower : to lose speed

Answer (score 4):

*braking*

It has the effect of slowing down.

Merriam Webster Dictionary

Examples of brake in a sentence. Can be used as a transitive verb.

I had to brake suddenly when a cat ran in front of the car.

Braked the car sharply when someone pulled out in front of us.